# News ticker: Recursion Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, settimeout

I was trying to implement a simple news ticker for a website I am creating.
Being new to JS and JQuery, I got the code off a website. The code works perfectly fine, but a too much recursion (firefox) error occurs when I shift the function call.
Original function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tick=function()
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({marginTop:"-30px"},700,function()
        {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker').removeAttr('style');
        });
        tick();//Old position for function call- works fine
    },4000);
};
tick();
});
```

The above code works, but when I shift the recursive call to outside the setTimeout function, the a recursion error. Slightly altered code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tick=function()
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({marginTop:"-30px"},700,function()
        {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker').removeAttr('style');
        });

    },4000);
         tick();//New position for function call-leads to unresponsive page
};
tick();
});
```

My question is this : shouldn't both the above codes works in the exact same manner? What changes when the location changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of [the setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) is to set another function to run after a specified amount of time. However, the timeout runs without blocking other code from executing -- the setTimeout function only **sets** the timeout, it executes immediately rather than waiting for the function passed to it to actually run. When you have the `tick()` call inside the `setTimeout` function call with a timeout of 4000 ms, you get the effect of rerunning the `tick()` every four seconds. However, once you move it outside the `setTimeout` call, it's rerunning instantly and infinitely as soon as you call it the first time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.
I still have one query, shouldn't the tick() call (in the second code example) be executed only after setTimeout has finished its execution?

Comment: Happy to help! It's a simple point but easy to miss if you don't understand what the `setTimeout` function is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, `tick()` doesn't call itself until the timer stops because the call to itself resides within the `setTimeout()` function. In the second case, `tick()` is instantly calling itself, with no timeout in between. This will call itself infinite times and if the browser didn't give you the recursion error and allowed it to continue, it would lock up or crash the browser eventually.

To show that, the second case can be simplified to:

```
var tick=function(){
    tick();
};
tick();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :).
But one thing is still not clear to me, aren't js statements executed sequentially? So shouldn't the tick() call happen once setTimeout is done with its execution?

Comment: setTimeout finishes its execution before the timeout necessarily finishes. All it's doing is **setting** the timeout, not blocking execution until it finishes.

Comment: @user3653438 `setTimeout()` is asynchronous, which means the JS execution doesn't wait for it to finish before it moves on to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply moving the `tick()` inside the `setTimeout`. Here's your new code. If you don't do this, `tick()` will be called immediately.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tick=function()
{
    window.setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({marginTop:"-30px"},700,function()
        {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker').removeAttr('style');
        });
        tick();//New position for function call-leads to unresponsive page
    },4000);

};
tick();
});
```